# Getting information from link in Python Flask

Tags: python, flask, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to make a simple web interface for my arduino using a raspberry pi. I want to click a link that i create in html and send the string "on" to the python program so it can tell the arduino to turn on.
Here's my python code

```
import serial
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import datetime
app = Flask(__name__)
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600)

@app.route("/<action>")
def action(action):
    print action 
    #command = ""
    #while command != "done":
    #       command = raw_input("what do you want? ")
    if action == "on":
            ser.write('1')
    elif action == "off":
            ser.write('0')
    return render_template('index.html', **templateData)

@app.route("/")
def display():
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    timeString = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
    templateData = {
            'title' : 'arduino',
            'time' : timeString
    }
    return render_template('index.html', **templateData)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080, debug=True)
```

and here's my html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
            <title>{{title}}</title>
    </head>
    <body>
            <p>The time at server is {{time}}</p>
            <p>
                The LED is currently off (<a href="/on">turn on</a>)
            </p>
    <body>
</html>
```

When someone clicks the link `turn on` I want the string on to be sent to the action method so that it can take it from there. Instead what it does is go to the `/on` directory which is not surprising. I've looked everywhere and can't find how to do this. This is my first time ever using Flask and I'm fairly new to python so please don't be too harsh if I'm completely off.

Comment: actually it will route to you to the `/on` which is currently not there, as you have two routes `/` and `/<action>`. you can change the the `/action` route as `/on` but if you want to pass a string I suggest you to use a `form` and then submit it.

Comment: you also have to change the first route as `/<string:action>, methods=["GET","POST"]`

Comment: isn't there a way i can just take the string from the link and send that?

Comment: also am I changing the route in the python code or the html?

Comment: It sounds like something is responding to the request before it gets to Flask. Are you running a server like Apache or nginx?

Comment: Yes I have apache running but the flask program is on port 8080 doesn't that mean it doesn't communicate with apache which is using port 80?

Answer (score 1):

You could just redirect after you take the action

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect

@app.route("/<action>")
def action(action):
    ...
    return redirect(url_for('display'))
```

Comment: Okay you sort of fixed my problem. However, the `return redirect(url_for('display'))` didn't work so I had to recreate the code from the display method. How exactly do I use the `url_for` to be able display the html from the display method?

Comment: url_for will redirect to the method that is specifies.  So in this case, it will redirect to the url_for -> display(). The URL is in the the route decorator, in this case '/'. Make sure you add the `from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect` part (the `redirect` is extra)